# C++ code cannot create output file on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: files, c++, c, output

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.16.7.

I'm trying to benchmark an SSD using the code I found here: https://cristianadam.eu/20160410/c-plus-plus-i-slash-o-benchmark/

This test uses three different APIs (C, C++ and POSIX) to perform file copying operation and measures the time taken to do it. However, no output files are generated in my filesystem. Also, no errors are reported. The test is supposed to generate the output file name by appending '.copy' to the input file's name.

Note that I have also tried these tests with the regular HDD and it's not working as well. Also, tried specifying the full path to both the source and destination file but the problem persists. I should also mention that the input file exists when the tests are ran and the test outputs a message to standard output with the time taken but, as I said, no output file in the filesystem.

Another interesting thing is that if the output file already exists when the test is ran, it gets deleted which again results in non-existing output file.

Also worth mentioning is that the file gets created if '<<' operator is used for writing into it (at least for the C++ test I tried that). However, I would like to avoid this approach.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code in the main-loop

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    {
        total += measure::ms(it->second, args[2].c_str(), dest.c_str(), inBuffer);
        ::unlink(dest.c_str());
    }
```

The `::unlink(dest.c_str())` removes the file after the test.

If you run the test for a very long time, you can see the files during the execution:

```
$ test_io.exe c big.bin 10000 &
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 134217724 Jul 23 13:45 big.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  70254592 Jul 23 13:54 big.bin.copy
```